# How to get a Facebook access token for a page with no app or app secret

Tags: facebook, graph, token

I am trying to automatically display wall posts from a Facebook page another website. I can use the Graph API explorer to get one manually. When I use the generated token in my code all is well. The problem is the tokens expire quickly. It just isn't practical to get a new code several times a day. I know there is a way to request an access token programatically - in my case via PHP, but all the examples call for an app secret. Since this is a page and not an app, there is no secret.

I have tried this:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FMY_SITE_URL&scope=user_status

What I get back is this:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}

I have tried using Fiddler to intercept the call from the Graph API explorer to see what I need in my code file, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: _“Since this is a page and not an app, there is no secret.”_ – well, then just create an app, makes things a lot easier that trying to “work around” not having an actual app. You don’t need to set up any app pages, canvas or page tab urls – just create the app, and maybe set up a domain for login, and then get access tokens with that app, make them long-lived, and query the Graph API with these tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For graph objects that are not private (public) you can use your app_id as an access_token.

Your app_id never changes so you don't ever have to renew it. The question is is the wall content yours?

If so you can easily use your `app_id` to accomplish this without having to request an access token everytime.

However, in order to have an app_id you need to create an application on facebook with a facebook developer account. As far as I understand there isnt a way to anonymously make request to the Graph API,

Comment: As the web developer for the company I have been given admin access to the page. I suppose I need to better education myself in Facebook terminology. It confuses the hell out of me. I don't understand how creating an app will help, and yet that has been recommended twice now. And even if I do, how do make an association between the app and the existing page?

Comment: Never mind. It makes sense now. I just created an app and requested an access token and the wall posts are working again. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to use app_id as access token to post data into my facebook page but I got the error "Invalid OAuth access token. ". If you have any example code, please update.

Answer (score 14):

1. Use the app-id to build this link to authorize the managing of pages
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_SITE_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
2. Exchange token for perm (longer token)
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=(from link1)
3. Visit this page, find the PAGE you want to post and copy the new access_token
   https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token= (from link2)
4. Use this last token (form link3) to post to page as app
5. <s>Take note as it will expire in 60 days. (FB no longer offering unlimited offline access token)</s>

<s>**Edit (2013 Oct 24):** 5th point no longer true, Page Access Tokens generated from long-lived User Tokens do not expire.</s>

**Edit (Feb 2016):** Tokens now "usually" expire in 60 days but can be invalidated at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. When I try the first step I get "An error occurred. Please try again later." I have tried similar steps in this process and that's the response I have usually gotten. Also, I don't want to manage pages or post to the page. I merely want to read wall posts from the page and post them to another site. Finally, do pages have secrets? I know apps do, but this isn't an app. That's been a major frustration in trying to resolve this, almost every example out there assumes that you are trying to attach to an app, not a page. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you changed the CLIENT_ID and SITE_URL vars?

Comment: Why " 5th point no longer true"??? Really it's expire date is 60 day or unlimited? http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/handling-expired-access-tokens/