# Login with facebook on native android app and send access token to remote server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm new to oauth concept. I'm working on an android app which uses facebook login to authenticate. After the authentication is done I want to send the access token to my remote server and make API calls to facebook(api calls from server using access token) and store user information on my server for future use. Is this method preferrable? I came to know that the access token expires after some time. So, Does the user have to login everytime the token expires and I have to send new token to server everytime a new token is cerated?
Any good suggestions on how to implement this are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the latest version of the Facebook SDK as I've not used it, but the previous version has a method "extendAccessTokenIfNeeded" which you could call every time the user runs your app.

Comment: So, the same access token can be used on the server side to make api calls?

Comment: Yes, you can just do an API call to your own server once you get the access token and use the access token from your server. I've done exactly this and it works without issue.

Comment: It looks like the method is deprecated, see https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java#L474

Comment: Of course you can still use it, I gather that FB improved the session handling in version 3 of the SDK so you would be best of checking the FB dev site.

Comment: Is it secure to send my access token in an API call from android to my server.

Comment: Provided you secure your API properly and use HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Yes process is working with the latest fb api!

You can extend the token for a duration of 60 days (i think), this token you can save on your local database and use that for making user actions on facebook.

the token is bounded to your app and have different grants.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

[How to get a Facebook access token for a page with no app or app secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237610/how-to-get-a-facebook-access-token-for-a-page-with-no-app-or-app-secret)