# Facebook posts on facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I make my (javascript) app to post to a Facebook page (that I own), without the need of explicit login (no pop-up windows) ?

From what I have read, I need a page_token to be able to post. Can I get this token using my credentials, or a facebook app ? I want to create post when a user does something in my app, but I want to avoid asking my users for their passwords. Thats's why I want to use my password for all users or use a facebook app for this.

Can it be done ?

Comment: Exposing your page access token in client-side code would be just plain stupid – everyone could steal it from there, and then use it to post in the name of your page.

Comment: I had no intention in doing that. But I appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need a **page access token** to post on a page on he page's behalf.

You can get a **never expiring** page access token that you can use while creating the posts. I've explained the procedure of getting the token with steps here: [Get access token to facebook page - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976350/get-access-token-to-facebook-page-wpf/23004308#23004308).

After you get this token, use this token with the call by adding the parameter `access_token`.

Comment: Thank you. I did also need status_update permission for my problem and to make the app public.